# Caring for the diseased

Tags: pathfinder-1e, disease

I know you can use the [heal skill](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/skills/heal.html#_heal) to *Treat Disease* to improve the chances of a diseased character to recover, but can you simultaneously give them *Long-Term Care* at the same time?

This is because some diseases the character will be suffering stat loss and will rapidly snuff it when their stat hits zero. Mitigating this will help the character survive longer and give them a chance to make their save.

I can't immediately see any reason why they *couldn't* receive both, but then the healer is both caring for the disease and giving them care; is this allowable or does it take two medics?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Treat disease only takes ten minutes, and long-term care is eight hours of light activity for up to six patients. These seem both logically and mechanically compatible, until there are more than six patients.

Comment: I've always imagined this as "Oh, you've got filth fever? Here, drink this, and hold this compress to your head, I'll check on you in a few minutes." With the 10 minute time being to prep whatever you need to do in order to treat the disease.

Answer (score 2):

You could, but it won't help like you want it to. From the [Afflictions](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/) section,

> Hit point and ability score damage caused by an affliction cannot be healed naturally while the affliction persists.

Therefore, you could restore *other* ability damage, but you cannot restore the CON lost to a disease until the disease is cured, except through magical means (such as [Restoration](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/restoration/), including lesser greater, or [Purify Body](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/purify-body/)).

Comment: That's not entirely relevant - the sufferer could have other hit point and ability score damage not caused by the affliction, which the Long Term Care could heal.

Comment: @yugozuno That's accurate but not how OP phrased it. Additionally, it's an important mechanic that was overlooked in the situation.

Comment: IMO, this information is completely relevant to the question at hand. The OP wanted to use long-term care to prevent the disease from causing too much damage, and that doesn't work.